# L'Hospital's Rule Intuition Infinity Case

Tags: limits, derivatives

Why does the following theorem hold true?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I forgot most of mathjax, but let me help you

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x), g(x)$ be a function such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ so we can write your problem as 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}}{\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}}$$
And you very well will be knowing the definition of a derivative so this is a small proof

And it works for infinity because you can redefine a function if f(x)=infinity as x tends to zero you can write it as h(x)=1/f(x) and the it tends to zero

Comment: I am still unsure how this simplifies to the above expression.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Rewrite it as

[image] to get to the 0/0 form. Should be obvious now.